# What is $5^{11\times31}$ congruent to in modulo $11\times 13$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

My attempt:

$$ 5^{11\cdot31}
≡5^{341} \pmod {143}$$

Using FLT where $$a^{p-1} ≡ 1 \pmod p$$

I get

$$≡(5^{142})(5^{142})5^{57} \pmod {143}$$
$$≡5^{57} \pmod {143}$$

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you use FTL on $143$ if it is not prime?

Comment: Ah, I guess not.

Comment: I see that on wolfram-alpha that the expression is congruent to 5 (mod 11x13). How can you show that this is true?

Comment: How would you reduce it mod $11$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $5^{11\cdot 31} \equiv 5^{1\cdot1} \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$, by Fermat's little theorem. 
Also, note that $5^{11\cdot 31} \equiv 5^5 \equiv 625 \cdot 5 \equiv 5 \pmod{13}$, again by Fermat's little theorem. Then by the Chinese remainder theorem, we must have that $5^{11\cdot 31} \equiv 5 \pmod{11 \cdot 13}$.

Comment: Or, $ $ mod $13\!:\ 5^2\equiv -1\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{5^4\equiv 1}\,$ so $\,5^{340}\equiv (\color{#c00}{5^4})^{85}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{85}\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot use Fermat's little theorem, you can use its generalization, Euler's theorem, which states that, if $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.  The method you were using will then work to start you on your way.